# Converting CodeIgniter view into PDF

Tags: php, pdf, codeigniter, pdf-generation

I'm trying to convert an output from a view file into PDF with TCPDF library. But I don't know how to configure it. Every tutorial I've read states that the PDF data should be included outside of view.
So the question is, it's a truth that I can't convert output from view into PDF?

Answer (score 0):

This has probably something to do with the way you would normally create PDF files with TCPDF.
You can't just take a view (or the output from one) and tell TCPDF to 'create my HTML as a PDF'. TCPDF needs you to tell it where to put what in which cells.

You could take a look at [this project](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) instead of TCPDF if you need to create PDF's from your views. I haven't tried it myself, but I've heard some good things about it.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I've finally found a solution of my problem. I'm using now mPDF library and I prepared a template for the invoice view in my model.